# Table containing symbols in a fixed-width column results in underfull hbox

Tags: tables, symbols, warnings

As part of a large table I have a column where each row contains a number of variables/symbols. The column should have a fixed width to fit the rest of the table. The problem is that the collection of symbols give a bunch of underfull hbox warnings. With large tables this quickly results into dozens of warnings. I have reduced the problem down to this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|}
\hline
$C_{X_u}$, $C_{Z_u}$, $C_{m_u}$, $C_{X_\alpha}$, $C_{Z_\alpha}$, $C_{m_\alpha}$, $C_{Z_{\dot{\alpha}}}$, $C_{m_{\dot{\alpha}}}$, $C_{X_q}$, $C_{Z_q}$, $C_{m_q}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be with the `array` package and `{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}` they fly away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fixed width column with very little flexibility for the line breaking and are trying to set justified text. The easiest way out is to make the text ragged right:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\raggedright
$C_{X_u}$, $C_{Z_u}$, $C_{m_u}$, $C_{X_\alpha}$, $C_{Z_\alpha}$,
$C_{m_\alpha}$, $C_{Z_{\dot{\alpha}}}$, $C_{m_{\dot{\alpha}}}$,
$C_{X_q}$, $C_{Z_q}$, $C_{m_q}$ \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(You need `\tabularnewline` here as `\\` gets redefined by `\raggedright` and will not work.)  Of course, this leaves lots of space at one side of the column: another way you is to alter the (fixed) column width.